# How can I make msbuild/VS create physical copies of files included as links on a build?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

In my c# VS2012 solution I have 3 projects: A,B, and C. Projects B and C include files (*.js and others) from A using the following include

```
<Content Include="..\A\**\*.js">
  <Link>%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
</Content>
```

I can see all referenced files from A as links in both B and C project in the Solution Explorer .

After building A,B, and C I can see files physically in the file system in project B, but not in project C. I compared the project files for B and C, but I cannot see anything that could control this behaviour. In general, I cannot find much information about what governs the behaviour of files included as links in csproj files.

Bottom question:

How can I make msbuild/VS create physical copies of files included as links on a build?

Comment: If you're saying that project B behaves like you wanted, but project C does not, it would be helpful to try to minimize the .csproj files (remove anything you can as long as the problem still occurs), and then post the two .csproj files in the question, so that someone may be able to identify the reason for the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.

I did what @Ran suggested (and I should have done in the first place) and I removed things bit by bit from both projects in order to find the difference. It turns out that the following lines made the 2nd project materialise *files included as links* on build.

```
<PropertyGroup>
 <OutputPath Condition="'$(TeamBuildOutDir)'=='' ">
   bin\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)
 </OutputPath>
 <OutputPath Condition="'$(TeamBuildOutDir)'!='' ">
   bin\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)
 </OutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```